# NumpyとChainerで、ベクトルの重み付き線形和の結果を合わせたい

Tags: python, chainer

ベクトルをスカラで重み付けして総和を取るために、
numpyとchainerのVariableを用いて、
以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
import numpy as np
from chainer import Variable
import chainer.functions as F

a = np.array([[10], [100], [1000]], dtype=np.float32)  # 重みの集合
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.float32)   # ベクトルの集合
print sum(a * x)  # ベクトルの重み付き和

a = Variable(a)
x = Variable(x)
print F.sum(a * x)
```

Numpyだとちゃんと計算されるのですが、
Variableに変換するとサイズが合わないと怒られてしまいます。

どのようなコードを書けば、
numpyとChainerで同じ結果を返すことができるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 確認ですが重みaはベクトルの各次元にたいする重みですか?それとも各ベクトルにたいする重みですか?

Answer (score 1):

`chainer.functions.batch_matmul`を使います。

```
>>> print(a*x)
[[   10.    20.    30.]
 [  400.   500.   600.]
 [ 7000.  8000.  9000.]]
>>> print(sum(a*x))
[ 7410.  8520.  9630.]
>>> print(F.batch_matmul(a, x, transb=True).data)
[[[   10.    20.    30.]]

 [[  400.   500.   600.]]

 [[ 7000.  8000.  9000.]]]
>>> print(sum(F.batch_matmul(a, x, transb=True).data))
[[ 7410.  8520.  9630.]]
>>> print(F.sum(F.batch_matmul(a, x, transb=True).data), axis=0).data) # sumもchainer側で行うには
[[ 7410.  8520.  9630.]]
```

a*xおよび和のベクトルが計算できていることがわかります。

Comment: 非常に助かりました。batch_matmulという関数で書けるのですね。ありがとうございます。